# Making a dialog that bugs me in Applescript

Tags: applescript

I know this question is kinda messy. I don't know how to make it more specific. I want to make an applescript that asks me every hour what I've been doing for the past hour.

The issue I'm having is that I want it to pop up, make a sound, and wait for my response. If I do a normal dialog, and I'm busy, it will go behind the other windows on my mac. I thought maybe having a persistent banner notification would be great, but applescript doesn't allow for much control over banners.

I want something to float over all windows so that I can see that the applescript has been waiting for a response from me until I fill out the dialog.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is a global floating window, similar to what LittleSnitch does. You can do that, but not with pure AppleScript. You'd have to write a Cocoa app.

Answer (score 1):

Adding an `activate` command just before a `display dialog` command in your **AppleScripts**, will ensure the pop-up dialog window will become frontmost and visible no matter what other apps and documents are currently opened *(until another app or document gets activated, thus bringing that item to the front)*.

This following **AppleScript** may be of some use to you.

Save this following **AppleScript** code as a "stay open application" in **Script Editor.app**.

When running your new **AppleScript** applet, it will remain running (because it has an `idle handler`) until you press "Cancel" in any of the dialog pop-ups or choosing to quit the app in the Dock.

*This code also logs everything it receives in the dialog pop-ups, to file for you.*

```
property myComputerActivitiesLog : (path to desktop as text) & "My_Computer_Activities.log"

property theDialog : missing value
property theDate : missing value
property insertTime : missing value
property logContent : missing value

on idle
    set theDate to (current date)
    set insertTime to "                               ------  " & theDate & "  ------  "
    
    beep 5
    say "It's time to log your activities"
    
    activate
    try
        set theDialog to display dialog ¬
            "Itemize my activities." default answer ¬
            "Itemize my activities for yhe past hour." & linefeed & linefeed ¬
            buttons {"Cancel", "OK"} default button 2 cancel button 1 ¬
            with title "Account For My Activities" with icon 1
    end try
    if theDialog = missing value then
        quit me
    else
        set logContent to insertTime & linefeed & (text returned of theDialog) & linefeed
        do shell script "echo " & quoted form of logContent & ¬
            " >> " & quoted form of POSIX path of myComputerActivitiesLog
        set theDialog to missing value
        return 3600 -- in seconds
    end if
end idle

on quit --  Executed when the script quits
    -- Additional code to perform (if any) goes here
    continue quit -- allows the script to quit
end quit
```

Comment: This is incredible! Thank you! You wrote the whole thing for me, except the nagging part. If i can't log my work in the moment, I might click on another window and bury my dialog box. How do I get that dialog box to come to the front?